# Send a string parameter to a controller (MVC3) from javascript (no ajax)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this simple javascript code:

```
var value = "I love programming";
window.location="Controller/Action/"+value;
```

In controller page, I have this:

```
public ActionResult(string value) {
   // do something
}
```

The problem is `value` parameter from controller. This is always null.

Why ?

Is the parameter type is restricted to int?  (without using ajax)

I can send an int to controller and it process the information correctly. But not string.

Comment: This should function window.location="Controller/Action?value="+yourValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to set up a route in global.asax to handle the string parameter, i.e:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapRoute(
    "ValueRoute",
    "{controller}/{action}/{value}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Yourcontroller",
        action = "Youraction",
        value = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

this is all top of the head stuff, so it may not happen for you.

**[update 1]** as you say in the comment below, changing the parameter name from value=>id *should* resolve the problem without recourse to addtional routes.

**[update 2]** - you could also, as per sandeep's comment, opt for the name-value pair on the url, i.e. window.location="Controller/Action?value="+yourValue

Comment: Doh ! Instead of `value`, I should use `id` as string? Am I right ?

Comment: michael - yes that would do the trick!! tho i had assumed you had an edge case for using the 'value' paramater, hence the 'new' route :)

Comment: +1. @MichaelSwan, if you don't want to edit the route; you can pass parameter using name-value pair window.location="Controller/Action?value="+yourValue

Comment: sandeep - yup that would work equally well (i'll add that to the answer to to give the 3 alternatives